# Error: NotYetImplemented - HTMLCanvasElement.Wo4J.exports.nyi

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-universal

[image: Unable to get what is the issue]

I am trying to build production build to deploy on server using angular-universal. I have also added domino to server.ts

Comment: Somewhere, your code or 3rd party lib is trying to use a canvas element while doing SSR, which is not supported by `domino`.

Comment: @David Yes, Do you have any suggestion to resolve it

Comment: Open up the compiled `main.js` file and try to identify what's causing the issue. Are you using svg, or open layers?

Comment: yes, I am using svgs

Comment: Like trying to write svg's inner html from code? This is not supported

Answer (score 0):

i'been the same issue, i fixed doing npm run build:ssr then i went to dist//server and opened main.js with note bloc there search "var Raster_context" and change his value for null, then y saved and y executed npm run serve:ssr i hope it work it was hard for me